# Treemap - Binary Search Tree - Java

Tags: java, set, binary-search-tree, treemap, red-black-tree

How can we insert some nodes into a binary search tree using the `TreeMap` that implements a Red-Black tree class. Then use the `entrySet` method to get back a `Set` version of the `TreeMap` through which we can Iterate over, and get ALL of the data.

Comment: Is this Java or what?

Comment: This has nothing to do with binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(); // create TreeMap

map.put("Key1", "Value1"); // insert a node
map.put("Key2", "Value2"); // insert another node

for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) { // iterate over entrySet
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Yours is a very basic question, so I suggest you give a look at the [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) documentation for more information.